# How to change the field Product Brand to Manufacturer?

Tags: magento2, attributes, manufacturer

Can someone please explain to me how I can change the field 'Product Brand' to 'Manufacturer'?

**From :**

[image: Product Brand]

**To :** 
[image: Manufacturer]

Answer (score 1):

Log in to your admin panel and navigate to **Stores -> Attributes -> Products** and create a new attribute called "Manufacturer" or edit the already existing "Product Brand" attribute.

If you want to remove the attribute "Product Brand" from the options. Navigate to **Stores -> Attributes -> Attribute Set** and remove the "Product Brand" attribute from the corresponding attribute set.

**Note: If you create a new attribute, don't forget to add it to attribute set!**

Comment: No problem! Mark as accepted if it answered your question co community remains clean :)